# Dynamically change the Firebase reference lookup in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue where if I have the following initial Firebase lookup

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Schedule").queryOrdered(byChild: "active").queryEqual(toValue : true)

ref.observe(.value, with:{ (snapshot) in

    for child in snapshot.children {
        print("\((child as! FIRDataSnapshot).value)")
        //To get week you need to access key
        print("\((child as! FIRDataSnapshot).key)")
    }
})
```

Which is executed when the view is first loaded, via viewDidLoad, in the view controller swift file; and now the user decides to got from active users as seen in the code above:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Schedule").queryOrdered(byChild: "active").queryEqual(toValue : true)
```

and wants only inactive items based on a selection from a drop down menu, how would I get the view to update automatically based on that selection from the drop down!?

Comment: When the dropdown is updated, cancel the current ref.observe() listener, and create a new one.

Comment: @Kato Thanx Kato... it worked!!!